# Maximal ideal of stalk

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Why is it that if after we restrict a global section x to a stalk at a prime ideal and its image is in the maximal ideal of the stalk, we can interpret this as x vanishes at p?

Answer (score 3):

Much of the intuition for scheme terminology can be explained by looking at their analogues for $\text{Spec}( \mathbb{C}[x] )$. Maximal ideals in this ring are in bijection with $\mathbb{C}$ itself through the association $\alpha \mapsto (x - \alpha)$. So, $\text{Spec}( \mathbb{C}[x] )$ realises $\mathbb{C}$ in the language of schemes through this bijection. Then an element of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ being in such a maximal ideal means that it is divisible by $(x - \alpha)$; in other words, that the function vanishes at the point $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.